# ThreadDelay Problem in Haskell (GHC) on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, haskell, ubuntu

I noticed odd behavior with the threadDelay function in GHC.Conc on some of my machines. The following program:

```
main = do print "start"
          threadDelay (1000 * 1000)
          print "done"
```

takes 1 second to run, as expected. On the other hand, this program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Control.Concurrent

main = do print "start"
          loop 1000
          print "done"
  where loop :: Int -> IO ()
        loop !n =
          if n == 0 
          then return ()
          else do threadDelay 1000
                  loop (n-1)
```

takes about 10 seconds to run on two of my machines, though on other machines it takes about 1 second, as expected. (I compiled both of the above programs with the '-threaded' flag.) Here is a screen shot from Threadscope showing that there is activity only once every 10 milliseconds: [image: Screenshot of ThreadScope showing that threadDelay of 1 millisecond sleeps for 10 milliseconds.]

On the other hand, here is a screenshot from ThreadScope from one of my machines on which the program takes 1 second total: [image: Screenshot of ThreadScope showing that threadDelay of 1 millisecond sleeps for about 1 milliseconds.]

A similar C program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i; 
  for (i=1; i < 1000; i++) {
    printf("%i\n",i);
    usleep(1000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

does the right thing, i.e. running 'time ./a.out' gives output like:

```
1
2
...
999

real 0m1.080s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.020s
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and if so, how can this be fixed? I am running ghc 7.2.1 for Linux(x86_64) on all of my machines and am running various versions of Ubuntu. It works badly on Ubuntu 10.04.2, but fine on 11.04.

Answer (score 4):

`threadDelay` is not an accurate timer. It promises that your thread will sleep for *at least* as long as its argument says it should, but it doesn't promise anything more than that. If you want something to happen periodically, you will have to use something else. (I'm not sure what, but possibly [Unix' realtime alarm signal](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/unix/System-Posix-Signals.html) would work for you.)

Comment: The link is not working anymore. One working https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html.

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, threadDelay only makes one guarantee, which is that you'll wait *at least* as long as you request. Haskell's runtime does not obtain special cooperation from the OS

Other than that, it's best effort from the OS.

It might be worth benchmarking your results for threadDelays. For example:

```
module Main where
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Time

time op = 
    getCurrentTime >>= \ t0 -> 
    op >> 
    getCurrentTime >>= \ tf -> 
    return $! (diffUTCTime tf t0)

main :: IO ()
main = 
    let action tm = time (threadDelay tm) >>= putStrLn . show in
    mapM action [2000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000] >>
    return ()
```

On my windows box, this gives me:

```
0.0156098s
0.0156098s
0.0156098s
0.0312196s
0.0312196s
0.0468294s
0.0624392s
```

This suggests the combo of delay and getCurrentTime has a resolution of 15.6 milliseconds. When I loop 1000 times delay 1000, I end up waiting 15.6 seconds, so this is just the minimum wait for a thread.

On my Ubuntu box (11.04, with kernel 2.6.38-11), I get much greater precision (~100us).

It might be you can avoid the timing problem by keeping the program busier, so we don't context switch away. Either way, I would suggest you do not use threadDelay for timing, or at least check the time and perform any operations up to the given instant.

Your high-precision sleep via C might work for you, if you are willing to muck with FFI, but the cost is you'll need to use bound threads (at least for your timer).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you forgot to compile with the '-threaded' option. (I did that once for 6.12.3, and consistently had 30 millisecond thread delays.)